# Wired settings icon gone

Tags: networking, network-manager, vmware

I'm running Ubuntu 22.04.1 on VMware Fusion, my host is macOS Ventura 13.

The wired connection icon is just not there. I tried almost everything I found online.

Changed Network adapter from Nat to bridged and vice versa, used `nmcli` networking command, then reinstalled and restarted.

Lastly I used `nmtui` but I end up getting this error :

[image]

Comment: maybe take a look at [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/628595/i-cant-deactivate-wired-ens33-on-nmtui)

Comment: Could you please in your post include the output of: `ip link show` and `cat /etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml`. Thanks.